# Replacing mechanical 8-throw switch with a digitally controlled implementation

Tags: switches, circuit-design, multiplexer

I have 8 independent resistive loads on a 1P8T mechanical switch that I use to test a power supply on a circuit board (the switch is connected at the power supply output). I want to replace the switch so that I can programmatically change the loads using an onboard PLC. I have considered an analog mux and then connecting the select lines to the PLC. However I am concerned about the effect of ON resistance tolerance, and ON resistance variation from channel to channel, on the accuracy of the test load resistance. In addition, the low ON resistance models are limited in voltage range (I need 40V). Any suggestions on a more effective implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a bunch of relays. If for some reason you can't drive the relays directly from the PLC you could add drive transistors to drive the relay coil.

And if you are going that far then you might also want to connect the transistors up to a priority decoder so you can switch one of eight lines with three control signals.

Comment: Can you elaborate? The relays I found are all double throw. How would I use relays to create 8 throw?

Comment: @JackOTrade use multiple relays

Comment: Tie the relays at one end, going to 8 different places at the other end. Voila. DIY SP8T relay

Comment: I see, 8x SPST relays with a common terminal. I forgot to mention that I am looking for an option that does not require both maximum relay count (8) and maximum control signal count (8).

Comment: @JackOTrade You can minimize control signal count with the priority decoder. I doubt you'll find a way around 8 relays though. You can also just use a shift register instead of a priority decoder if you only ever sequence through the relays.

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen and all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Wire each relay coil to an independent PLC output. Use on normally open (NO) relay contact to switch in each load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYbd9w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>